# Why can't I include echo inside a variable?

Tags: php, functions

So for example, say I have a piece of text from a field I want to call.

So I set the variables like this:

```
<?php
$text = get_field('text_field');
$outputtext = echo $text; ?>

<p><?php $outputtext ?> </p>
```

Is that not possible, and if so, why? Is there a particular reason why PHP is set up that way or something?

Comment: That's just not how PHP's [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) works. Just do `<p><?php echo $text; ?> </p>` instead. There various ways to set up the output string depending on your needs.

Comment: @DaveRomsey okay understood. Is there a reason that's not how PHP works though?

Comment: `echo $text` (can also be written as `echo($text)`) is a command that sends a string to the output stream (i.e. the response body for a web page or the screen on the command line) so trying to assign it's returned value (which is always nothing) to a variable simply makes no sense. If you want a more detailed explanation, it'd probably be best to ask over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a WordPress question, but to do what you want you'd need to use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

For your example, it's totally not needed or recommended, though.

[Echo shortcut syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (e.g. `<?= $text ?>`) might interest you.